# Adding a footer to each printed page from an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with an existing ASP.NET/C# website that has a new requirement: when a user prints a page from the website, each printed page must contain a footer with a set text.  That is, if the HTML table will require two printed pages, each page must contain the footer.

I have read how to add to my CSS file for a print-only scenario, but what I haven't found is how to do the pagination to know when to add in the footer.

The content that is being is printed is contained within an asp:Table.

Thanks in advance for your time and any assisitance you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be the one to tell you this, but...

This can't be done via html, css, javascript, or anything you will have control over.

If you need this type of functionality, you're going to need to look at other options, such as a Word mail merge or Crystal reports, or SQL Server Reporting Services.

***Edit***

Sorry.  I should have said:

"You can't do this ***reliably*** for all browsers".  For ***consistent*** results (which is what we all want in most cases, isn't it?)  you're going to need to look at other options, such as a Word mail merge or Crystal reports.

Comment: Why are people voting you downwards?  There is no way to have a footer appear reliably on every page using the built-in printing of the browser.

Comment: +1 for the edit, doing this across browsers consistently in HTML is a wasted effort IMO, they make reporting tools for that

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the input.  This organization is only using IE 6, so that is the only browser I have to support.  I agree, it is a complete waste of time, but that doesn't stop them from making it a requirement.  The closest I can get to a comprimise is to disable printing for certain pages all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a block-element which you can position with `position: fixed`. I came across [this](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=PrintingHeaders) article from 2004 which details that technique. Unfortunately back then support was very limited but this situation should be much better now. I definitely know that this works in IE 8 (having clicked through each of the 7k+ CSS tests ...).

Comment: I apologize, I should have indicated in my question that all users are on IE 6.  position: fixed doesn't seem to work with IE 6.

Comment: Not only it doesn't seem to not work. It definitely doesn't work. CSS 2 support is basically non-existent in IE 6.